# R, create tables using base::by

Tags: r

I try to create 2by2 tables out of my data.

I have a list/or a dataframe which ist similar to the following

```
my.list <- list(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
df <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1), c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
names(df) = c("test1", "test2", "test3")

reference <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
gender <- c("m", "w", "w", "m", "m")
```

to create simple 2bx2 - tables I did:

```
lapply(list, table, reference)
```

this results in a list with tables like this:

```
[[1]]
   reference
    0 1
  0 1 1
  1 1 2

[[2]]
   reference
    0 1
  0 0 2
  1 2 1

[[3]]
   reference
    0 1
  0 0 3
  1 2 0
```

Now I have an other vector "gender" by which I want to split the tables.

I tried

```
by(df, gender, table, reference)
```

but all I get is

> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' muss atomar sein für 'sort.list'

which translates to: 'x' has to be atomic for 'sort.list'

Can someone explain to me what that means and how I can produce my 2by2 tables?

my desired output should look like this:

```
"m"                         "w"

[[1]]                       [[1]]
   reference                   reference    
    1                        0 1
  0 1                        0 1 0
  1 1                        1 1 1

[[2]]                       [[2]]
   reference                     reference  
    1                       0 1
  0 2                       1 2 1

[[3]]                       [[3]]
   reference                     reference  
    1                       0 1
  0 2                       0 0 1
                            1 2 0
```

Thank you guys very much!

Comment: Hey, I edited the question to make the desired outcome more clear. Basicly I to create multiple subgroups for an analysis of a big dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you swap the "m" and "w?" If not I'm still unsure about your desired output

You can just take your already-working function and apply it to each index created with `by$gender`

```
df <- data.frame(test1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 test2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 test3 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 reference = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
                 gender = I(c("m", "w", "w", "m", "m")))

by(df, df$gender, function(x) lapply(x[, 1:3], table, x$reference))

## df$gender: m
## $test1
##    
##     0 1
##   0 1 0
##   1 1 1
## 
## $test2
##    
##     0 1
##   1 2 1
## 
## $test3
##    
##     0 1
##   0 0 1
##   1 2 0
## 
## --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
## df$gender: w
## $test1
##    
##     1
##   0 1
##   1 1
## 
## $test2
##    
##     1
##   0 2
## 
## $test3
##    
##     1
##   0 2
##
```

Comment: Yes! That works like i wanted it to. Thank you very much.